# Why is my Applications window different in OS 10.7

Tags: finder

Most of my windows are normal but the root Applications window and some others do not have adjustable columns or triangles to open a folder. Has anyone seen this before and how do I fix it?

I tried deleting the finder preferences; no change.

Abnormal

[image]

Normal

[image]

Comment: Pictures of what you consider normal & not normal would help

Comment: What happens when you deliberately change the Toolbar settings for the Applications window? That is, change from 'Text Only' (the present setting) to 'Icon and Text'. Experiment with the Customize Toolbar... option and try the Default set.

Comment: Been there, done that -- and every other Finder preference and window view option available before and after deleting Finder preferences and re-launching the Finder.

Answer (score 2):

I re-installed Lion and that restored normal windows.